# Convert cells of strings to array in Excel without VBA

Tags: arrays, excel

I've got a series of cells containing text, a cell repeating itself ('MYTITLE') :

```
MYFIXTITLE    
foo1    
bar1    
MYFIXTITLE    
foo2    
bar2    
MYFIXTITLE    
foo3    
bar3
```

And would like to convert it to 2 column-array like this :

```
first column : MYFIXTITLE for all cells
second column : foo(y) \n bar(y)
```

(y) being the line number of this array, \n being a new line.

Do you know how to do this in non VBA-Excel? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=$A$1
```

and copy down and in **C1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,3*ROW()-1) & CHAR(10) & INDEX(A:A,3*ROW())
```

and copy down:

[image]